# How can I use Navigation (NavHost) in nested fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I'm trying to open `Fragment2` from `Fragment1(TransformFragment)`
throught click item in `RecyclerView`. I tried to use `Navigation (NavHost)` to solve this problem.

`Fragment1` code as below:

```kotlin
class TransformFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var transformViewModel: TransformViewModel
    private var _binding: FragmentTransformBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding
        get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        transformViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[TransformViewModel::class.java]
        _binding = FragmentTransformBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val recyclerView = binding.recyclerviewTransform

        val adapter = TransformAdapter()
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        transformViewModel.texts.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { adapter.submitList(it) }

        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    class TransformAdapter() :
        ListAdapter<String, TransformViewHolder>(
            object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<String>() {

                override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: String, newItem: String): Boolean =
                    oldItem == newItem

                override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: String, newItem: String): Boolean =
                    oldItem == newItem
            }
        ) {

        private val drawables =
            listOf(
                R.drawable.avatar_1,
                R.drawable.avatar_2,
                R.drawable.avatar_3,
                R.drawable.avatar_4,
                R.drawable.avatar_5,
                R.drawable.avatar_6,
                R.drawable.avatar_7,
                R.drawable.avatar_8,
                R.drawable.avatar_9,
                R.drawable.avatar_10,
                R.drawable.avatar_11,
                R.drawable.avatar_12,
                R.drawable.avatar_13,
                R.drawable.avatar_14,
                R.drawable.avatar_15,
                R.drawable.avatar_16,
                R.drawable.avatar_17,
            )

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TransformViewHolder {
            val binding = ItemTransformBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
            return TransformViewHolder(binding)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TransformViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.textView.text = getItem(position)
            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(
                ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(holder.imageView.resources, drawables[position], null)
            )

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

                // my navigation(NavHost) code

            }
        }
    }

    class TransformViewHolder(binding: ItemTransformBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        val imageView: ImageView = binding.imageViewItemTransform
        val textView: TextView = binding.textViewItemTransform
    }
}
```

I tried to use this:

```kotlin
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)

navController.navigate(R.id.nav_detail)
```

`nav_detail` to navigate `Fragment2`, and My Fragment Container. This's my XML. I know that to display Dynamiclly Fragments, you must use `FrameLayout`, but it produces errors and the fragment container is OK.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fragment_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fragment_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <!--
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fragment_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fragment_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
        -->

    
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the correct answer in [Android developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs).

```kotlin
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

            it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.nav_detail)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `findNavController()` to navigate between fragments, you've to make sure that you've setup with activity properly first.

So, in your activity layout first add container, parent need nod to be `FrameLayout` itself, I'm gonna make use of `ConstraintLayout` below.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!--    We declare attribute id to hook with MainActivity.java class-->
<!--    Attribute name will change behavior of simple fragment to NavHostFragment-->
<!--    Keep width and height to match_parent so that all our fragments take whole space-->
<!--    We change this NavHost to behave default NavHost-->
<!--    Attach our app navigation graph to this NavHostFragment-->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now let's hook container as an acting host for activity.

**MainActivity.kt**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // NavigationController to set default NavHost as nav_host_fragment.
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp()
    }
}
```

`onSupportNavigateUp` function helps you to navigate back to previous fragment on action trigered or called specifically on any view with `navigateUp()`.

Now you want to navigate from Fragment1  ->  Fragment2.

1. Make sure you've added two fragments to navigation graph.
2. Connect first fragment to second with action.
3. Keep track of destination Id's to call correct one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name=".FirstFragment"
        android:label="FirstFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_first_fragment_to_second_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name=".SecondFragment"
        android:label="Authors"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" />

</navigation>
```

Now finally once action is triggered call action with id like below on controller.

```kotlin
yourListItemView.setOnClickListener {
    findNavController(R.id.action_first_fragment_to_second_fragment)
}
```

That's it.

Please check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started), it has a good information.